# How can I get Google maps to show on my website

Tags: google-maps

I am unable to implement google maps on my website, despite generating an API key for it and configuring it correctly on the website.

http://josebaattard.com/about/

Comment: Hi and welcome! Thanks for the link to your site. However, it would be helpful to post more info here so that people don't have to follow a link to your personal site. For example, you can copy and paste the error that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

the console tells you the error:

```
Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError  
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
Your site URL to be authorized: http://josebaattard.com/about/
```

You have limited your API-Access to an certain url and this one is not allowed.